# How to populate text area based on drop-down selection

Tags: javascript, html

I'm super mnoob at this. Can I use js to populate an html text area based on an html drop-down selection and if so how do I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may have meant something like this:
Tell me if it's help you.

HTML:

```
<h1>Note Generator</h1>

<div class="left">
CSTemplates
<p>
<select class="c10" onchange="showCSTemplates(this);"> 
<option selected="selected" value="" id="Templates">Please select a template...</option>
<option>1</option>
<option>2</option>
<option>3</option>
<option>4</option>
<option>5</option>
</select>
</p>
<p>
<textarea cols="30" rows="20" readonly="readonly" id="CSTemplates">
Templates will auto-populate 
here depending on the 
selection made from the 

[CSTemplates] 

drop-down list.
</textarea>
</p>
</div><!--left ends here-->
```

JavaScript:

```
function showCSTemplates(sel){   

locations =[ "", /*this remains blank for first selection in drop-down list*/ 

/*option 1*/                 
" This is template 1 that  will appear in a textarea keeping its formatting as  is. ",

/*option 2*/                
" This is template 2 that  will appear in a textarea keeping its  formatting as  is. Credentials:  Contact Info: ",

/*option 3*/                 
" This is template 3 that  will appear in a textarea keeping its formatting as  is. Donec tortor lorem,  ornare vitae commodo nec,  sagittis et nunc. Maecenas sagittis quam ",

/*option 4*/                 
"etc",

/*option 5*/                 
"etc...", ];
                   srcLocation = locations    [sel.selectedIndex];    
   if (srcLocation != undefined && srcLocation != "") {      
                  document.getElementById('CSTemplates').innerHTML= srcLocation;   
 } 
}
```

Comment: Yes! This! Thank you so much! I should be able to figure out how to do what I want with this. Thank you again!

Comment: It didn’t work how I thought it would. I’ll try and describe what I need in more detail, when I select “item1” from the drop down list I would like to populate a list of associated items, and I would like all of these populated items to be selectable so I can drag and drop them in a different area. I hope that makes sense!